# React router - click on Productcard and redirect to a component with details of that clicked card,

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am making website for clothing store as my practice.
i dont known how make only one file used in all components using map function and when clicking on one a card, that card information will render in product view component. i dont known backend development yet.
can this be achieved by usecustomshooks or make json file?

Comment: Before custom hooks try to React ecosystem. There are a lot of tutorials out there. This is the official documentation. https://reactjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Map will go through all objects in the array and use them as an argument of a function. For example `[1, 2, 3].map(num => console.log(num))` will print out numbers inside of an array. The same way you can use it to fill in the data in the product view component:

```
{itemData.map((data)=> <ProductViewComponent data={data}/>)}
```

Use return () after the arrow function if you want to write more code inside.

Comment: [
    {
      "id":"1",
      "title": "Steve Jobs",
      "image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/4137OkbPQ4L._SX331_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg",
      "author": "Walter Isaacson",
      "url": "https://www.amazon.com/Steve-Jobs-Walter-Isaacson/dp/1451648537",
      "price":"100$"
    },] i have data like this and i use   {Products.map((item) => (
        <Product {...item} key={item.name} />
      ))} to show data. In my product there is link with path of product veiw . when clicked on product there data should render in product veiw. i hope you understand and help me.